# FluentValidation: upgrading PropertyValidatorContext to ValidationContext<T>

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I'm currently using FluentValidation 8.6.2, and attempting to update to 11.1.0. (.Net Core 3.1) I've run into a problem in a custom validator that needs to modify the Severity of the current validator. When changing `PropertyValidatorContext` to `ValidationContext<T>`, how can I fix this line?

```
context.Rule.CurrentValidator.Options.Severity = some value...
```

`ValidationContext<T>` does not have a Rule property. Is there a way to get to the Severity property?

Comment: FluentValidation has several upgrade guides for major versions. Please read those.  E.g. https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/upgrading-to-9.html

Comment: Additionally, there is a whole page on setting the severity: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/severity.html

Comment: Thanks for the above. Neither addresses the problem though. The upgrade guides are how I found out I needed to change to ValidationContext<T>, but they don't explain what to do about the missing Rule property. The severity page explains what to do for built-in validators, but don't address how to manage Severity dynamically in a custom validator. I need a way to get to the Severity setting for the CurrentValidator via the ValidationContext.